# Non-linear Orthographic Zoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, touch, zooming

**Introduction:** I have a level in Unity and the camera is set to a top-down view in orthographic projection. I want to Zoom in/out with a pinching-gesture with touchinput in a Range of an orthographic size of [100, 2000] units.

**The Problem:** I have 2 Solutions for this, that dont satisfy me.

One is a zoom with a linear amount of units, the higher the orthographic size gets (zoom out) the slower it zooms out. And if I am zoomed In, the zooming gets faster. This doesnt feel good and intuitive with touch input.

The other is a non-linear Solution that works O.K. but isnt really precise and with lots of zooming in and zooming out it always zooms more in than out.

```
//Solution Liniear
camera.orthographicSize += deltaZoom;

//Solution Non-Liniear (scales with orthographic size)
deltaZoom *= (camera.orthographicSize / 100);
camera.orthographicSize += deltaZoom;
```

**Question:** What mathematical solution is there, so the camera zooms slower when the ortographic size is low and faster when it is high? I also would like it to be precise as in if I pinch-to-zoom with my fingers, it zooms excactly the amount of units out.